# Android runtime permissions - how to test UI

Tags: ui-automation, robolectric, android-testing

Can i use robolectric to test runtime permissions in android ? I am talking about when the system pops up a window asking the user for the permission - how will i know ?  I suspect i can use UIAutomator to gain access to the system screens but can it be used with robolectric ? What is the recommended way ? I need a way to interact with the system window for run time  permissions.  I see a class called [UiDevice](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiDevice.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need it to do it with `Robolectric`?

I haven't used this framework yet for this kind of purpose, so I don't tell you if it is possible. Moreover, I think that the best way already for making automated UI tests is using along two Google's frameworks: `espresso` and `uiatomator`.

Here you would find why: [Espresso & UIAutomator - the perfect tandem](http://qathread.blogspot.com/2015/05/espresso-uiautomator-perfect-tandem.html)

Check also: https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/

For Android system UI elements, like notifications, screen lock or highlighted in topic runtime permissions, `uiatomator` would be enough.

Especially as there is an article about how to handle it with `uiatomator`: [Handling Android runtime permissions in UI tests](https://medium.com/@hitherejoe/handling-android-runtime-permissions-in-ui-tests-981f9dc11a4e#.2qx31ocy5)

Hope it help. Happy testing!